# Airflow operator to download email to s3

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm working on writing a DAG that will download a file from email directly to s3. I figured there would already be operators I can use to help with this. I found the following [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/imap_attachment_to_s3_operator.html) but I'm not sure what the parameters 'imap_conn_id' and 's3_conn_id' should be.. any help with this would be appreciated. If you know a better operator with examples, that be great to!

Comment: they are `conn_id`s for [`Connection`s](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#connections); i guess this needs 2 connections: 1 for IMAP & other for S3

Comment: What version of Airflow do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no much documentation about those connections, so you will have to look into the code of the corresponding hooks to find out what to put in the connection fields:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/imap_hook.py
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py

Comment: I use version 1.10.10